# Non-convex optimization over convex set with separable objective function and linear equality constrains

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a problem as follows.

$\max\limits_{\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nf(\mathbf{x}_n)\\
s.t.\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbf{x}_n=\mathbf{c},\\
0\le\mathbf{x}_n\le1,$

where $0\le a_n\le1$, $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{x}_n\in\mathbb{R}^K$, and $f(\mathbf{x}_n)=\sum_{m=1}^M(-1)^m\frac{\mathbf{q}_1(m)^T\mathbf{x}_n+b_1(m)}{\mathbf{q}_2(m)^T\mathbf{x}_n+b_2(m)}$ with $\mathbf{q}_1(m),\mathbf{q}_2(m),b_1(m),b_2(m)>0$, the gradient of $f$,i.e., $\Delta f$, is Lipschitz continuous.

I am stuck in this problem over days. I appreciate any help you give.

Comment: I am confused with the definition of $f.$ The term  $$\frac{q_1^Tx_n+b_1}{q_2^Tx_n+b_2}$$ does not depend on $m.$ Hence, if $M$ is even, $f(x_n)=0,$ if $M$ is odd, $f(x_n)= - \frac{q_1^Tx_n+b_1}{q_2^Tx_n+b_2}.$ Also, am I right to assume that $q_1>0$ means $q_{1i}>0$ for $i=1,\ldots, K$? What specifically do you want? a closed form solution? a method?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. The coefficients are depend on $m$. I do not pursuit a closed-form solution, just a method or some clues.

Comment: If it's any consolation, this is a non-convex problem (and a hairy one at that), so you _should_ struggle with it. There is simply no reliable way to solve it. Magnusseen's papers are a good overview but they are likely not to be _too_ encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem falls in the class of Fractional Programming Problems. [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:JOTA.0000026129.07165.5a), [this one](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/1055678031000105242) and [this one](https://www.jstor.org/stable/168864?seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents) should give you a starting point. Best of lucks!!